# I want an app that does X and works on both Android and iOS. Can I ask that here?

Tags: discussion, questions

Specifically I want an app that does what [Pocket](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.citc.wallet&hl=en) does that I can use on Android and iOS without using a web app.

Would such a question be on topic here and or Ask Different? If so, which site is more appropriate?

More generally, is it okay to ask how one could perform a task in a *cross platform* manner (including Android) on topic? Is it only on topic if I'm asking how to do the Android part of the task?

Comment: What's your reason for requiring that the app have a version for both platforms?

Comment: It securely syncs encrypted personal information like passwords via drop box. I'd like to be able to access the information on both devices on a single service

Comment: And to pre-empt you asking the question, I've used SplashID for years as a cross-platform password/info storage app across Palm, Android, Blackberry and PCs. They have an iOS version (note paid app though). http://splashdata.com/splashid/ it uses a PC/Mac as the sync hub over wifi, and can backup to Dropbox etc.

Comment: Note: cross-posting within Stack Exchange is _okay_ so long as what you're asking is tailored to the particular site you're asking on (no simple copy-and-paste, please). It's a good idea to indicate you're cross-posting and to link to the other question.

Comment: @GAThrawn ouch, $10 apiece. I'm not a cheapskate but since I need to get such an app *twice* I was hoping for a free or cheap solution. Pocket's free and I'm kind of amazed it's not on iOS. I wish Springpad had a secure data section or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's fine.  Wanting your services consolidated is a perfectly OK criterion for potential solutions, as is not using a web app.

Things to note:

- "Is there an app" is discouraged; you'll get better answers with "How can I" anyways, even if you know they'll all mention apps.
- We can't help you if you want us to provide info on how well the iOS version works and that sort of thing. Which is not to say users can't tell you, but rather that you shouldn't ask for or expect it.

Comment: Is there a reason for the anti-app question policy btw? Even if it's not the only way to solve a problem it's how most smartphone users are used to framing problems, and it's probably reflected heavily in search terms.

Comment: @BenBrocka "Is there an app" type questions tend to encourage a deluge of one-liner answers with every conceivable related app posted by different people, these are known as "shopping recommendation" questions are dislallowed in the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions). "How do I do X" questions tend to encourage posts with well thought out solutions to the problem that may or may not include an app, and if so are more likely to give the pros and cons of the choices, and be more helpful.

Comment: @GAThrawn true. There might be dozens of apps to securely sync data (there are) but there are only specific ways I can keep that info in sync across iOS and Android.

Comment: I think at least in the case of app recommendations, we're OK with losing out on search traffic. Unless the powers that be at SE change their stance on those sort of questions :P